# Code-First Migrations and DataDirectory for LocalDb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, localdb

It looks like the command "Update-Database" uses the Default Project's directory as the AppDomain instead of the Start-up Project's.

I have a separate class library project that contains everything related to the database access, including the models and migrations, let's call it **Project.Data**. One of the unit tests for this project requires me to run it on a LocalDb. So I created a connection string within the unit test's app.config.

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True
```

but the DataDirectory's value is null when I run the command "Update-Database". And using the AppDomain's work directory is kinda unreliable here.

How can I use the Unit Test's work directory when I run the "Update-Database" when the models and migrations-relate codes are in a separate class library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to you use the `ProjectName` or `StartUpProjectName` parameter when executing the update-database command.

See here for more details: [update-database command reference](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/#Update-Database)

```
Update-Database [-SourceMigration <String>] [-TargetMigration <String>] [-Script] [-Force] 
  [-ProjectName <String>] [-StartUpProjectName <String>] [-ConfigurationTypeName <String>] 
  -ConnectionString <String> -ConnectionProviderName <String> 
  [-AppDomainBaseDirectory <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```